# How to match both partial ahk_class and whole ahk_exe at the same time

Tags: autohotkey

## What I want to achieve is this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#ifwinactive ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame: ahk_exe FOXITPDFEDITOR.EXE
```

`ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:` part is only a partial match of `ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:3c0000:8:10007:10`. But this `#ifwinactive` doesn't work. Any idea?

## Here's the full background:

I want to create a hotkey for a Foxit reader floating panel.

```
#ifwinactive ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:3c0000:8:10007:10 ahk_exe FOXITPDFEDITOR.EXE
```

Problem is the `ahk_class` part changes for every new instance. So, I want to specify only partial `ahk_class` and whole `ahk_exe` at the same time like this.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#ifwinactive ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame: ahk_exe FOXITPDFEDITOR.EXE
```

But that doesn't work. Then I learnt `SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx` is the fix for partial `ahk_class` match.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
#ifwinactive ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame: ahk_exe FOXITPDFEDITOR.EXE
```

But this doesn't work either. How should I achieve this?

## edit

Based on user3419297 suggestion, I tried this but failed.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
GroupAdd, Foxit_reader_floating_panel_group, ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  ; for the rest
```

I also tried creating another ahk_group for msedge.exe, and failed too.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
GroupAdd, chrome, ahk_class Chrome_
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  ; for the rest
```

then I tried another version and worked.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
GroupAdd, Foxit_reader_floating_panel_group, ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:bd0000:8:10007:10
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  ; for the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
; auto-execute section (top of the script):


; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance:

full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}

SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
GroupAdd, Foxit_reader_floating_panel_group, ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:

SetTitleMatchMode 2  ; for the rest
; ...

        RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===
        
; ...

#IfWinActive ahk_group Foxit_reader_floating_panel_group

    F1:: MsgBox, Foxit reader floating panel is active

#IfWinActive
```

**SetTitleMatchMode** cannot work outside of the auto-execute section, of a hotkey/hotsring-definition or a function because its a command, not a directive as **#IfWinActive**.

**EDIT**

If you want to use RegEx as the standard SetTitleMatchMode in your script (rarely the case), then you don't need to create the group in the auto-execute section and use directly `#IfWinActive ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:`

However if you want to use another SetTitleMatchMode e.g. SetTitleMatchMode 2 (often the case) within hotkeys/hotsrings/functions then you have to add it each time in their definition.

**EDIT 2**

If the program is running with admin privileges, then AHK won't intercept the key presses. Try to run the script as administrator as in the edited code.

For more details read https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs.

**EDIT 3**

Another approach:

```
; auto-execute section (top of the script):

SetTimer, create_group, 200 
; ...

        RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===
        
; ...

create_group: 
    WinGetClass, ActiveClass, A
    If InStr(ActiveClass, "BCGPMiniFrame")
    {
        WinGet, active_id, ID, A
        GroupAdd, Foxit_reader_floating_panel_group, ahk_id %active_id%
    }
    If InStr(ActiveClass, "Notepad") ; Notepad, Notepad2, Notepad3, Notepad++
    {
        WinGet, active_id, ID, A
        GroupAdd, Notepad_group, ahk_id %active_id%
    }
    ; ...
return

#IfWinActive ahk_group Foxit_reader_floating_panel_group

    F1:: MsgBox, Foxit reader floating panel is active
    
#IfWinActive ahk_group Notepad_group

    F1:: MsgBox, Notepad_group is active

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question though.  With `SetTitleMatchMode RegEx` on the top of script, can I remove `GroupAdd` line and directly use `#IfWinActive ahk_class BCGPMiniFrame:`?

Comment: See EDIT in this answer and note the second SetTitleMatchMode  in the auto-execute section.

Comment: I created an empty .ahk file and pasted your full code, and unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: See EDIT 2 in this answer.

Comment: thanks for your edit. Unfortunately, that failed too. I make an edit in my question showing some more info.

Comment: Try also EDIT 3.

Comment: This idea is inspirational, yet pretty complex. Do you know any universal solution for this type of question, partial matching ahk_class, without using regex for the whole file?

Comment: That way ( = using SetTimer and only once in the script) you can create as many groups of windows with partial matching ahk_class as you want, without using regex. I've extended the example under EDIT 3.